# How to search & display relative records based on user id

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am a beginner in Laravel and I want to display the relative student records after teacher logged in. I have already implemented login page.

This is my tables

```
     Teachers
+----+--------------+
| id | teacher_name |
+----+--------------+
| 1  | John         |
+----+--------------+
| 2  | Tommy        |
+----+--------------+

     Students
+----+--------------+---------------+------------+
| id | student_name | course        | teacher_id |
+----+--------------+---------------+------------+
| 1  | Emma         | Learn Laravel | 1          |
+----+--------------+---------------+------------+
| 2  | Olivia       | Learn Java    | 2          |
+----+--------------+---------------+------------+
| 3  | Charlotte    | Learn Laravel | 1          |
+----+--------------+---------------+------------+
```

Generally, I will get teacher ID in session and execute this query in PHP

```
SELECT * FROM Teachers, Students WHERE students.teacher_id = '$teacher_id';
```

How to search his students information after teacher logged in and display it in a simple table in Laravel 5?

Comment: Have you setup `Teacher` and `Student` models yet?

Comment: If you mean `php artisan make:model Teacher` and `php artisan make:model  Student`. Yes, I have

Comment: And the relationships defined in each as well?

Comment: no...just default model.

Comment: You should normalize your database by establishing relationships/foreign keys. This also ensures data integrity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Gayan said in his answer adding the relationships to your models should be your first step:

Student Model:

```
public function teacher ()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Teacher::class);
}
```

Teacher Model:

```
public function students ()
{
     return $this->hasMany(Student::class);
}
```

But unlike Gayan, it makes more sense to me to get the teacher with students:

```
$teacher = Teacher::with('students')->findOrFail($teacherID);
```

you will need to pass the techer variable to your view from your controller:

```
return view('example.template', ['teacher', $teacher]);
```

and in your blade template something like:

```
<table>
    @forelse($teacher->students as $student)
         <tr>
             <td>{{ $student->name }}</td>
         </tr>
    @empty
         <tr>
             <td>No Students found</td>
         </tr>
    @endforelse
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `Student` model put the following relationship.

```
public function teacher ()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Teacher::class);
}
```

Then in your could query like

```
$teacherId = 123; // Set this
$studentWithTeachers = Student::with('teachers')->where('teacher_id', $teacherId);->get();
```

Comment: how to loop through all the records and display it in home view?